# how can I do from px to vh in array js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var states = [{ $zIndex: 4, width: 568, height: 568, top: 0, left: 0, $opacity: 1 },]
```

I want the width to be 100vh
I tried doing vh next to the number but error occurs

Comment: can you please show where are you using `states` ?

Comment: Pass it as a string like this `width: "100vh"` not like this `width: 100vh`.

Comment: @AdilBimzagh ty so much

Comment: @37bandiko where are you using `states` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the width as a string. Eg width: "100vh"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width: '100vh'`

```
var states = [{ $zIndex: 4, width: '100vh', height: 568, top: 0, left: 0, $opacity: 1 },]
```